# How to view Django Rest Framework Source Code in VS Code

Tags: django, docker, visual-studio-code, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django Rest Framework.  I am working on a project running in Docker containers.  I would like to view Django Rest Framework source code in VS Code.

When I right-click on anything from the following line and click `Go to Definition` I get the message `No definition found for 'rest_framework'`

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
```

How can I view django rest framework source code in VS Code, particularly if I'm running my projects in containers?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Go to virtualenv ( python environments )

- /env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/restframework